# Ubuntu gets stuck in loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, firmware

Whenever I try to boot Ubuntu I get a firmare bug that says the ACPI region does not cover the entire command / response buffer. Thats followed by soft system lockup for 22 seconds on cpu 2 followed by a hard lock up on cpu 1. When I run the system compatibility diagnostic thing it says I have a firmware error and need to update my e microcode to 0xb2 or later. What does this mean and how would I fix this? I'm assuming it's related to not being able to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Intel releases microcode updates to correct processor behavior as documented in the respective processor specification updates. AMD releases microcode patches to correct processor behavior as documented in the respective processor revision guides. Login to a virtual console and install the system processor microcode that is compatible with your computer's CPU.

1. When the system is booting immediately before the system is about to lock up access the virtual console by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. To login from a virtual console:

   1. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Run the following command to display the CPU manufacturer (Intel or AMD):

   ```
   cat /proc/cpuinfo
   ```
3. Run one of the two following commands depending on whether your computer's CPU manufacturer is Intel or AMD.

   ```
   sudo apt install intel-microcode # Intel CPU  
   sudo apt install amd64-microcode # AMD CPU
   ```
4. Reboot the system.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

If you can't access the virtual console in Step 1, all you need to do to get into a virtual console is for the Linux kernel to be loaded and the kernel is the first thing to load when the computer is booting, so press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+F3 earlier and maybe it will work. Otherwise you can install the firmware updates by booting from an Ubuntu live USB and using [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) to run a command or interactive shell with a special root directory (your Ubuntu installation on the hard drive).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't even make it to the loading screen now, it just starts throwing errors in the virtual console. I updated my original question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: All you need to do to get into a virtual console is for the Linux kernel to be loaded and the kernel is the first thing to load when the computer is booting, so press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+F3 earlier and maybe it will work, otherwise you can install the firmware updates by booting from an Ubuntu live USB and using [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery).